# how to replace and add object to list python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

```
return_so = [{'id': 1, 'has_hub': False}, {'id': 2, 'has_hub': False}, {'id': 3, 'has_hub': False}]

hub_so = [{'id': 1, 'has_hub': True}, {'id': 62, 'has_hub': True}, {'id': 13, 'has_hub': True}, {'id': 2, 'has_hub': True}]
```

Hi, I want to merge 2 array and when there is a duplicate dict by "id" I want to pick the dict that `has_hub = True`

```
expected result = [{'id': 1, 'has_hub': True}, {'id': 2, 'has_hub': True}, {'id': 3, 'has_hub': False}, {'id': 62, 'has_hub': True}, {'id': 13, 'has_hub': True}]
```

thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this but taking advantage of the fact that dictionaries in python are now preserving insertion order (3.7 implementation detail, 3.8 standard), you can do this:

1. Populate a dictionary, using `id` as the key
2. If conflict is found, then only overwrite if `has_hub` is true
3. Convert dict back into list

Here it is:

```
d = {}  #create dict

for item in return_so + hub_so:
  if item['id'] not in d or item['has_hub']:
    d[item['id']] = item

expected_result = list(d.values())
```